# Kafka GlobalState Store Is empty

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a Spring Boot Application and want to access a global StateStore of a topic.
Sadly the result is always null...
It does not look like, the stateStore is filled at all.

So first the data is in the topic:
[image]
The value also contains the information I want, so that is there.

I took a look at the [following example](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/7.1.1-post/src/main/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/GlobalStoresExample.java) and added the StateStore like this:

```
@Autowired
void buildPipeline(StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder) {
    streamsBuilder.addGlobalStore(
            Stores.keyValueStoreBuilder(Stores.persistentKeyValueStore(stateStoreName), STRING_SERDE, CustomSerdes.TenantConfigurationSerde()),
            inputTopic,
            Consumed.with(STRING_SERDE, CustomSerdes.TenantConfigurationSerde()),
            () -> new GlobalStoreUpdater<>(stateStoreName));

    streamsBuilder.build();
}
```

And I tried to read it the following way:

```
    public TenantConfiguration getTenantConfigurationByTenantId(String tenantId) {
        StoreQueryParameters<ReadOnlyKeyValueStore<String, TenantConfiguration>> storeQueryParameters = StoreQueryParameters.fromNameAndType(stateStoreName, QueryableStoreTypes.keyValueStore());
        TenantConfiguration tenantConfiguration = Objects.requireNonNull(streamsBuilderFactoryBean.getKafkaStreams()).store(storeQueryParameters).get(tenantId);
    return tenantConfiguration;
}
```

I do not get an exception or anything, just tenantConfiguration is null. So the StateStore is found in my opinion, but the data is not there.

Is there a difference between "addGlobalStore" and "globalTable"? The later one creates a KTable that is globally available but from my understanding this is done via a StateStore in RocksDb as well, so I'm not sure if there is a difference or not.
I also tried it with this but I had the same issue:

```
   streamsBuilder.globalTable(inputTopic, Materialized.<String, TenantConfiguration, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as(stateStoreName)
                    .withKeySerde(STRING_SERDE)
                    .withValueSerde(CustomSerdes.TenantConfigurationSerde()));
```

if somebody has an idea on why the data is null I would by very thankfull!